# Wnat Ansible List Output to be plain string

Tags: list, ansible

I have an ansible script that outputs a list per so:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "SG's are [[u'12345', u'54321']]"
}
```

I want to convert this list into a simple string so it says the following:

```
SG's are 12345 54321
```

I've tried the following lines of code that don't work:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "SG's are {{ sg_ids|join(' ') }}"

Output: "msg": "SG's are [u'12345', u'54321']"
```

Following won't work either:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "SG's are {{ sg_ids|join(' ')|to_yaml }}"

Output: "msg": "SG's are '[u''sg-12345'', u''54321'']'\n"
```

Comment: your code looks right. you sure the variable is a list? can u run debug module with `var: sg_ids` ?

Comment: Please post the full playbook. Where does `sg_ids` come from?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code isn't working is because you are trying to join a list of lists. Flattening the list of lists to a list should fix the issue:

`{{ sg_ids|flatten|join(' ') }}`   (I can't test right now)